# Does every real skew symmetric matrix map some non-zero vector with non-negative entries into a vector with non-negative entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Find a matrix $A$ (or prove no such matrix exists) such that $A=-A^T$ and if $v≥0$ (pointwise) and $Av≥0$ (pointwise) then $v=0$.

Although no solution has yet been given we have currently established no such $2×2$ or $3×3$ matrix exists. Ideally a proof would be given for all $n×n$ matrices (or a single counter example of any dimension). Thanks to all of you who have contributed.

Comment: What did you attempt?

Comment: What is -T? The inverse of the traspost matrix of A?

Comment: Skew-symmetric matrix has $A=−A^T$, not $A=A^{−T}$, the latter is called [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix). And rotation by 180° is one, and satisfies your condition.

Comment: yes I meant $A=-A^T$, I haven't been able to come up with anything as an example yet which is why I'm asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such matrix exists. Tucker's existence lemma asserts that if $A$ is skew-symmetric, then there exists a vector $x$ such that $x\ge0,\,Ax\ge0$ and $Ax+x>0$ (so that $x$ must be nonzero). See Giorgio Giorgi (2014), [*Again on the Farkas Theorem and the Tucker Key Theorem Proved Easily*](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Again-on-the-Farkas-Theorem-and-the-Tucker-Key-Giorgi/2d802c64e5ecb6f08244b9fd4fce0d6337fdec45), p.15, lemma 3.

Comment: Great find. I wonder "why" this is geometrically. I was thinking in terms of spectral decomposition into the 2D invariant planes, but it is hard to picture how the map in them relates to the first quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a proof of the question as it was in the original title,  approximatively : "Existence of an antisymmetric matrix such that the image by it of the positive orthant $O_+$ has a $\{0\}$ intersection with  $O_+$ ?".
>
> My answer is that no such  matrix exist for the $2 \times 2$ case, and that an infinity of solutions exist for the $3 \times 3$ case.

**$2 \times 2$ case :**

The general form of an antisymmetric matrix is (for any real $a$)

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-a\\a& \ \ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

which corresponds to a $\pi/2$ rotation composed with a homothety with ratio $a$.
In the $a>0$ case the image of the first quadrant is the second quadrant, sharing the half of the ordinate axis with the first quadrant. A similar conclusion for the case $a<0$, this time with the positive $x$-axis.

**$3 \times 3$ case :**

The general form of an antisymmetric matrix is (for any real numbers $x_0,y_0,z_0$)

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\ \ 0&-z_0& \ \ y_0\\ \  \ z_0& \ \ 0&-x_0\\-y_0& \ \ x_0& \ \ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

with the following geometrical interpretation : $AV= U_0 \times V$ where

$$U_0=\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\y_0\\z_0\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore the image $R(A)$ of $A$ is the plane (2 dimensional vector space) orthogonal to $U_0$.

It is visually intuitive that $R(A) \cap O_+=\{0\}$ (where $O_+$ = closed positive orthant) if we take any $V_0$ in the **open** positive orthant ($x_0,y_0,z_0 > 0)$.

Proof of this fact : Let us assume, as said upwards, that $x_0,y_0,z_0 > 0$. Then

$$V(x,y,z) \in R(A)\cap O_+ \ \iff \ xx_0+yy_0+zz_0=0 \ \ \text{with} \ \ x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0$$

which is impossible unless $x=y=z=0$ (consider for example that $x >0$ ; we would have a contradiction with $xx_0+yy_0+zz_0 > 0$).

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for your answer however I am concerned about the 3x3 case. In your example I understand that you have the matrix A = [0,1,-1; -1,0,1; 1,-1,0]. It seems to me that the vector v=[1,1,1] still works though. Av=0 and v≥0 and v≠0

Comment: I have re-written my answer in a completely different way.

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for your edit however I still don't think it works. My counter example above still stands and I have appended a more fleshed out explanation to my question. I hope this helps! Thank you very much for your time so far.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding comes from the fact that I consider on one side vectors $v$ and on the other side vectors $Rv'$ with $v' \neq v$ in general.

Comment: Since you take $U_0$ with entries of the same sign there is a vector from the first octant, a multiple of $U_0$, that is in the kernel. This violates his condition that the only vector from the first octant with image in it is $0$. And if you take $U_0$ with entries of different signs the plane will intersect the first octant. So I think this proves that no such 3x3 matrix exists either.

Comment: @JeanMarie, My apologies! I just realized my title and my question were slightly out of sync as to be extremely miss leading as to what I was asking. You are correct if you are answering the question in the title however this is not the question I intended, I have changed the title so that it matches the body, which is in fact the question I intend to ask. Sorry for wasting your time on this blunder of mine

Comment: @fred This interpretation is specific to 3D and does not generalize. I do not know whether it holds in all dimensions.